# In socket, the sound is sent with delay

Tags: numpy, sockets, audio, scipy

I'm making a sound exchange program with socket programming, but I want to send the sound in a thicker format.
During thickening, the sound is sent to the client side with a delay, how do I solve this?

server code:

```
def send_audio(self):
        p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
        stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16,
                        channels=self.CHANNELS,
                        rate=self.RATE,
                        input=True,
                        frames_per_buffer=self.CHUNK)
        
       
        
        while self.is_running:
            data = stream.read(self.CHUNK)
            audio_data = np.frombuffer(data, dtype=np.int16)
          
            converted_data= signal.resample(audio_data,int(len(audio_data)*self.PITCH_SHIFT_FACTOR))*1.4
            converted_data = converted_data.astype(np.int16)
            converted_data_bytes = converted_data.tobytes()
            self.client_socket.sendall(converted_data_bytes)
            
           
            if not self.is_running:
                break
        
        stream.stop_stream()
        stream.close()
        p.terminate()
```

Client code:

```
def receive_audio(self):
        p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
        stream = p.open(format=self.FORMAT,
                             channels=self.CHANNELS,
                             rate=self.RATE,
                             output=True)

        while self.is_running_recv:
            data = self.server_socket.recv(self.CHUNK)

            if not data:
                break

            if self.event.is_set():
                stream.write(data)

        stream.stop_stream()
        stream.close()
        self.server_socket.close()
        p.terminate()
```